# cannot bind name attribute with dynamic value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<table>` that has multiple columns, each having an `<input>` with a `name` attribute. To make the name unique, I want to append the row and column index. How do I bind `<input name="label['0'][cindex]">` (where `cindex` is an integer from zero to n-1) in my Vue template?

```html
<th v-for="(col, cindex) in cols" :key="cindex" :col="col">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="label['0'][cindex]" placeholder="Add Label" value="" v-model="column_labels[cindex]" class="form-control label text-center">
    ...
  </div>
</th>
```

Comment: you should to bind the `name` attribute using  `v-bind` or `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Vue's bindings by prefixing the `name` with a colon, then construct the name as a string:

```js
:name="'label[\'0\'][' + cindex + ']'"
```

The entire input field:

```html
<input type="text" :name="'label[\'0\'][' + cindex + ']'" placeholder="Add Label" value="" v-model="column_labels[cindex]" class="form-control label text-center" />
```

Comment: can i store full tr to database even with new input field? when i store input value get not storing

Comment: @samjadps This isn't really a question I can answer here. There is a lot of information I don't have that I would need. I would recommend asking a new question about that specific problem with enough detail to understand what the desired behavior is and what behavior you're seeing instead, and I would suggest including the relevant front-end and back-end code in that new question as well so we can properly examine what your code is doing.